# How to ask Rubocop to check method defined on specific class?

Tags: ruby, rubocop, rubocop-nodepattern

I want to discourage the usage of `notify` of `CustomController`, but not `AnotherCustomController`. Is there a matcher in rubocop that allows it to check `notify` is from specific class?

```rb
class CustomController
   def notify(message)
      puts 'notify is deprecated'
   end
end

class AnotherCustomController
   def notify(message)
      puts message
   end
end
```

Currently, `(send nil? :notify ...)` is matched to both of them. I want to match only from CustomController.

```rb
class MatchClass < CustomController
   def run
      # This should be matched by rubocop
      notify('test')
   end
end

class NotMatchClass < AnotherCustomController
   def run
      # This shouldn't be matched by rubocop
      notify('this is another notify method')
   end
end
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In the general case, it's not possible, because `rubocop` analyses things statically.

If I give you the following code, you won't be able to tell me if it should be matched or not:

```rb
class Example < SomeOtherClassYouDoNotKnow
  def run
    notify("You would need to know the definition of the parent class")
  end
end

def anywhere
  something.notify("You need to know what `something` is")
end
```

You could look for the particular pattern you gave but you could have both false positives and false negatives.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find inheritance class name, but i could find code's path. So I did like this.

```rb
node.location.expression.source_buffer.name.include?('app/jobs')
```

Answer (score 0):

When I want to deprecate a method and want to discourage people from using it, then I would use the Ruby StdLib [`Deprecate`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.1.2/libdoc/rubygems/rdoc/Gem/Deprecate.html) to mark it as deprecated and show a warning:

```
class CustomController
  extend Gem::Deprecate

  def notify(message)
    puts 'notify is deprecated'
  end
  deprecate :notify, "AnotherCustomController#notify", 2023, 11
end

class AnotherCustomController
  def notify(message)
    puts message
  end
end
```

Calling `CustomController#notify` with return a warning like this:

```
Customercontroller#notify is deprecated; use AnotherCustomController#notify instead. It will be removed on or after 2023-11-01.
```